# Is there a way to organize the photos in Google photos besides creating albums manually?

Tags: google-photos

I have a bunch of folders on my Android. I've selected multiple photos to backup to Google photos.

However, I notice that everything gets backed up into one common folder. This is very messy. All my good memories, photos of important documents, profile pics, everything is merged into one giant mess.

Is there a way to keep the organization in Google photos as it is in the phone's folder structure? Or any other way to categorize them together?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing you can use is the search feature. It must be one of the best search features I've seen. You can search by location, event, activity, date or pretty much anything you can think of. It's not exactly what you're looking for but I think its the closest match.

[Image showing search features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPKck.png)